# How to do pagination with sockets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, pagination

I have a question about pagination...

In the normal pagination you have these 2 variables in some language (example Javascript):

```
var page = 1;
var count = 5;
```

And then the value of start variable is this:

```
var start = (page - 1) * count;
```

And you can do a request of pagination that returns "**start** to **start+count**" list elements.

Independent of pagination system, a **Socket** system is listening, and when a new element is added or removed in the BBDD, the element is added or removed it in the "Client Side" list.

If the "Client Side" list is sorted by created date, maybe we can solve the problem doing something like this:

```
var page = 1;
var count = 5;
var socketElements = 0;
```

If **adding a new element** via Sockets -> **socketElements ++**

If **removing a element** of "Client Side" list via Sockets -> **socketElements --**

```
var start = ((page - 1) * count) + socketElements;
```

In this case works because is sorted by created field, and the new element always will appear in the list.

But... And if the "Client Side" list is sorted by another field? How I know if the new element via Sockets will appear or not in "Client Side" list? What is the best way to implement pagination with Sockets listening in the same list?

*I'm asking the concept of pagination with socket system, for any language, but in particular I'm implementing in AngularJS (Client) and NodeJS (Server).*

Thank you!